# Connecting my MySQL database ran with docker-compose to Django

Tags: python, mysql, django, docker-compose

I can't figure out how to get it connected.

When I run the below command:

```bash
python manage.py check --database default
```

I get the error below:

```
(2013, "Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0")
```

When I log into *MySQL* with the CLI, I don't see the database when I run the `show databases;` command:

```py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'db-1',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'example',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '3306'
    }
}
```

```
version: '3.1'

services:

  db:
    image: mysql
   configuration)
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: example

  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 3306:3308
```

It took me 5 errors to get to this point so I haven't tried a whole lot but messing with the Django settings.

Answer (score 0):

Drop the `network_mode` directive, wrap your ports, and set the user password correctly. (ROOT_PASSWORD variable is required).

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  db:
    container_name: local-db
    image: mysql:8.0
    environment:
      MYSQL_USER: 'user1'
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'password'
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'rootpassword'
      MYSQL_DATABASE: bears-local-db
    volumes:
      - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - "3308:3306"
```

At Django settings, you were using the wrong `username`, also, your user had no password to login with. And pointing to the wrong port where your service is available.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'bears-local-db',
        'USER': 'user1',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '3308',
    }
}
```

Comment: I switched up the code a bit. New error is in the question edit 